# Access to value into a link_to data confirm sentence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to access to the pseudo of my user into my confirmation message. I've try to use #{} parenthesis, and also another <%=%> tag to did it. But is not working. Do you have any idea of what I can use to achieve it ?

```
<%= link_to expel_group_path(group, idz: user.id), method: :patch, remote: true, :data => {:confirm => 'you want to kick out #{user.pseudo} of the group #{group.name}'} do %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpolation is possible only between double quotes (or heredoc syntax)

```
"you want to kick out #{user.pseudo} of the group #{group.name}"
```